# how to fix an error during uploading custom dataset in to colab?

Tags: python-3.x, google-colaboratory, drive

I have followed all the steps described in most tutorials on how to upload your custom dataset into google colab. but I am getting an error which I try a lot to fix but not working.

I am trying to train a CNN model using my custom dataset. I try to upload it on colab using the code snippet given in most tutorials.

the following error is displayed when I run the code snippet

```
Downloading zip file

---------------------------------------------------------------------------

HttpError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pydrive/files.py in FetchMetadata(self, fields, fetch_all)
    236                                                  fields=fields)\
--> 237           .execute(http=self.http)
    238       except errors.HttpError as error:

6 frames

HttpError: <HttpError 404 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/https%3A%2F%2Fdrive.google.com%2Fopen%3Fid%3D1RqLx88tx2FCV0Z3CHsqVtx7S3_ffE-UW?alt=json returned "File not found: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1RqLx88tx2FCV0Z3CHsqVtx7S3_ffE-UW">


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ApiRequestError                           Traceback (most recent call last)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pydrive/files.py in FetchMetadata(self, fields, fetch_all)
    237           .execute(http=self.http)
    238       except errors.HttpError as error:
--> 239         raise ApiRequestError(error)
    240       else:
    241         self.uploaded = True

ApiRequestError: <HttpError 404 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/https%3A%2F%2Fdrive.google.com%2Fopen%3Fid%3D1RqLx88tx2FCV0Z3CHsqVtx7S3_ffE-UW?alt=json returned "File not found: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1RqLx88tx2FCV0Z3CHsqVtx7S3_ffE-UW">
```

```
#this is the code snippet I have taken from tutorials to upload dataset to google colab.
    !pip install -U -q PyDrive

    # Insert your file ID
    # Get it by generating a share URL for the file
    # An example : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1iz5JmTB4YcBvO7amj3Sy2_scSeAsN4gd/view?usp=sharing
    zip_id = 'https://drive.google.com/open?id=1RqLx88tx2FCV0Z3CHsqVtx7S3_ffE-UW'

    from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth
    from pydrive.drive import GoogleDrive
    from google.colab import auth
    from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials
    import zipfile, os

    # 1. Authenticate and create the PyDrive client.
    auth.authenticate_user()
    gauth = GoogleAuth()
    gauth.credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
    drive = GoogleDrive(gauth)

    if not os.path.exists('MODEL'):
        os.makedirs('MODEL')

    # 2. Download Zip
    print ("Downloading zip file")
    myzip = drive.CreateFile({'id': zip_id})
    myzip.GetContentFile('model.zip')

    # 3. Unzip
    print ("Uncompressing zip file")
    zip_ref = zipfile.ZipFile('model.zip', 'r')
    zip_ref.extractall('MODEL/')
    zip_ref.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

OMG. after a long hour (almost 8 hours) researching on the internet and brainstorming i found the answer. if any one who is new working on colab and face a similar error here is how i solved this error. The problem on the above code is the way we assign the file id. zip_id = 'https://drive.google.com/open?id=1RqLx88tx2FCV0Z3CHsqVtx7S3_ffE-UW'. most of the tutorial I have seen told us just to take the file id by right clicking the file in google drive and copy the share link address. but the file id is not the whole thing we copied. the file id is only after the id= which is in my case 1RqLx88tx2FCV0Z3CHsqVtx7S3_ffE-UW. After giving this as an id the error is gone. Hope this response will help other colab starters.